# Rewrite htaccess old oscommerce links

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite all the old oscommerce links to a new website. But I am having trouble with part of the URL I need to rewrite.

The link looks like this:

```
http://www.domain.com/product_info.php?cPath=3_72&products_id=129&osCsid=6j3iabkldjcmgi3s1344lk1285
```

This rewrite works for the above link:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/product_info\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cPath=3_72&products_id=129&osCsid=([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/apple/air.html? [R=301,L]
```

But will not work for:

```
http://www.domain.com/product_info.php?cPath=3_72&products_id=129
```

My problem is that I want the rewrite to work no matter if the `&osCsid=6j3iabkldjcmgi3s1344lk1285` part is included or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can achieve this by not specifying the closing delimiter ($)

Give this a try:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/product_info\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cPath=3_72&products_id=129
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/apple/air.html? [R=301,L]
```

By not putting the $ at the end of the regex string you are basically saying: match any string that starts with ..., no matter what comes after

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job just fine:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cPath=3_72&products_id=129
RewriteRule ^product_info\.php$ http://www.domain.com/apple/air.html? [R=301,L]
```

1. There is no need for separate condition `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/product_info\.php$` -- this part can be (actually, SHOULD BE, for better performance) moved to RewriteRule.
2. This is enough `^cPath=3_72&products_id=129` -- it tells "When query strings STARTS with ...". No need to include optional/non-important parameters `osCsid=([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)`.
3. This rule is to be placed in .htaccess file in website root folder. If placed elsewhere some small tweaking may be required.